# Inconsolata font on Android Studio

Tags: windows, fonts, intellij-idea, antialiasing

I want to use `Inconsolata` font on a intelliJ editor (Android Studio) on Windows but it looks messy.

I managed to load `inconsolata` by adding some antialiasing options on  studio.exe.vmoptions. I just added these options

```
-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on
-Dswing.aatext=true
-Dsun.java2d.xrender=true
```

and now the font loads but it looks too much crappy to use. Actually any font on this ide looks crappy. Here's a screenshot of the same font on SublimeText **right** and on Android Studio **left**

[image]

Anyone knows if you can use this font on intelliJ based editors or if there are some issues associated with this font?

Comment: I tried other monospaced fonts (like Consolas and Deja Vu Sans) and all of them look very thin compared on how they see on Eclipse or Sublime Text

Answer (score 0):

We can simply use google fonts  It's very easy to implements. only you have to follow these steps.

**step 1)** Open layout.xml of your project and the select font family of text view in attributes (for reference screen shot is attached)
[image]

**step 2)** The in font family select More fonts.. option if your font is not there. then you will see a new window will open, there you can type your required font & select the desired font from that list i.e) Regular, Bold, Italic etc.. as shown in below image.

[image]

[image]

**step 3)** Then you will observe a font folder will be auto generated in /res folder having your selected fonts xml file
[image]

Then you can directly use this font family in xml as

```
      android:fontFamily="@font/inconsolata"
```

[image]